# Customizing section for adding bullet or image

Tags: graphics, sectioning, titlesec

I am a newbie to TeX and I'm trying to create a template CV for learning LaTeX class and new commands.

I want to create an `\iconsection` command get 2 values: first, an icon filename or pifont symbol, and second, the section's name. For example `Education` section with a book icon.

I could add icon file using `\titleformat` but I don't know how to add an image as a parameter to `\section`

```
\newcommand\SecImage{%
\llap{\makebox[3em][l]{%
  \raisebox{-.65\totalheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2em]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    }%
  }%
}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\Large\bfseries\thesection\hspace{1em}}%
    \SecImage\thesection\hspace{1em}\hangindent\wd0\strut#1\strut%
  }

  % i want something like this
  \newcommand{\iconsection}[2]{%
     \section{#1 image file path}[#2]%
   }

  \newcommand{\iconsection*}[2]{%
     \section{#1 pifont symbol like ding{41}}[#2]%
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems, Its not that simple I'm imagined. so I should go with normal sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out How to insert symbol before section part. for alignment I should have more train I guess

```
\newcommand{\iconsection}[2]{% 
\titleformat{\section}         % Customise the \section command 
  {\Large\scshape\raggedright} % Make the \section headers large (\Large),
                               % small capitals (\scshape) and left aligned 
  {}{0em}                      % Can be used to give a prefix to all sections, like 'Section ...'
  {#2}                           % Can be used to insert code before the heading
  [\titlerule]
  \section[#1]{#1}
}
```

sample usage for pifont symbols

```
\iconsection{Education}{\ding{45}}
\iconsection{Hobbies}{\includegraphics[width=12px]{hob} }
```